# How to search in TreeView for specific charcater

Tags: c#, winforms

I have TreeView in C# and I want to grab everything that is after the ":" sign, I dont know where or what to do actullay...

```
    if (TV.Focused)
    {
        string str = "";
        string NameStr = "";
        if (TV.SelectedNode.Text == "دليل الحسابات")
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i <= TV.SelectedNode.Text.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (TV.SelectedNode.Text.ToCharArray(i, 1).ToString() == " ")
            {
                if (TV.SelectedNode.Text.ToCharArray(i + 1, 1).ToString() == ":")
                    break;
            }
            str += TV.SelectedNode.Text.ToCharArray(i, 1).ToString();
            NameStr = TV.SelectedNode.Text.ToString().Substring(str.Length + 2, TV.SelectedNode.Text.ToString().Length - str.Length - 2);
        }
        txtAccID.Text = str;
        txtAccName.Text = NameStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `String.Split`

Comment: how to spilt? sorry im new in C# i was VB.net student!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled a couple of ways

Using [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

```cs
var input = "hello:world";
var split = input.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(split[0]); //outputs "hello"
Console.WriteLine(split[1]); //outputs "world"
```

or using [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
var input = "hello:world";
var positionOfColon = input.IndexOf(':');
var afterColon = input.Substring(colonPosition + 1, input.Length - colonPosition - 1);
Console.WriteLine(afterColon); //outputs "world"
```

As mentioned in the comments, you may need to consider cases where your input has multiple colons.

For example, if you have the string `hello:world:three`, then `Split` will create an array of three items `hello` `world` and `three`, which may not be what you want. If you want everything after the *first* colon, then using `IndexOf` would be your best option, and it would return `world:three`. If you only want what is after the last colon, then you could use [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `IndexOf`, and that would just return `three`.

Comment: You should use the overload of string split that takes an integer `2` to limit this to two values in the array. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_  For example, try `input = "Hello:World:Three"`.